# Assembly 'amqmdnet' could not be installed because existing policy would keep it from being used

Tags: sql, sql-server, ibm-mq, sqlclr

Hi,
I try to register amqmdnet.dll (a part of IBM WebSphere MQ for Windows) in SQL server in order to deploy SQL SQL 
CLR stored procedure to use it for MQ mesaging.

The code is:

```
create assembly amqmdnet                                                
from 'c:\mssql\assembly\amqmdnet.dll'                                   
with permission_set = unsafe
```

The server's response is:

```
Msg 6586, Level 16, State 1, Line 1                                     
Assembly 'amqmdnet' could not be installed because existing policy      
would keep it from being used.
```

-- @@version :

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5835.0 (Intel X86)               
    Mar  1 2013 18:44:43                                                   
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation                          
    Enterprise Edition on Windows NT 5.2 <X86> (Build 3790: Service Pack 2)
```

CLR is enabled, TrustWorthy is on, other CLR procedures work well.

How to resolve the issue?

Comment: What version of MQ are you using? I was able to successfully register WMQ 7.5.0.0 version amqmdnet.dll on SQL Server 2008 R2. No service packs applied for both MQ and SQL Server.

Comment: @Shashi amqmdnet.dll version is 7.5.0.2

Comment: Have you made any progress? Are the MQ assemblies in GAC? if so, can you un-register MQ assemblies from GAC and then run CREATE ASSEMBLY in SQL Server? To un-register MQ assemblies you can run "amqiregisterdotnet.cmd /u" bat file from <mq installation>/bin directory.

Comment: @Shashi Thank you! After unregistering asms from GAC the dll was successfully registered in SQL. Unfortunally guy, who worked on it, is on vacation now. He will continue working after some weeks :)

Comment: Great! There seems to be some issue with SQL Server if policy files are in GAC.